Make Neotree show every buffer like :ls?
https://github.com/nvim-neo-tree/neo-tree.nvim
I have a autocmd in Neovim that does :Neotree buffers dir=/ to show all my buffers, however buffers don't show up in the list until I switch to them, so :ls shows all buffers while Neotree doesn't.

It seems that there is an issue #885 in the NeoTree plugin issue list about that subject.
